# Adding transition to opacity of divisions using jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var x = $("#slideshow div");
  // var y = $("#slideshow div img");                  
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    x[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) 
    {slideIndex = 1;}

  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000);
}
```

This is a function that selects all the divisions of the id 'slideshow' and then changes the opacity of all divisions to 0 and display to none.
Then it changes the slideIndex's division display to block and opacity to 1.

In CSS, I have added transition for opacity to be 2s.

```
#slideshow div {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
   transition: opacity 2s;
  /*-webkit-transition: display 1s linear;*/
}
```

But the divisions appear one by one without any transition of opacity. What need to be done here? Thanks!

Comment: opacity will not work if you have display:none. Try commenting out display related code and test once again.

Comment: Changing the `display` value prevents the use of a transition. Removing the lines where you change the `display` value.

Comment: @palaѕн I did that, but now all the divisions are fading away one below the other. How do I display them at one fixed place. Thanks!

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Please read above the comment above.

Comment: @pcgamer CSS Grid or absolute positioning will help with that. I'd go with the former unless you need legacy browser support.